# Why is my Azure Function set to `Disabled` upon deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In Azure DevOps I have a build pipeline which creates an archive of a project containing two Azure Functions. I then have a release pipeline which deploys this zip archive to the Function App.

[image]

The release pipeline was built using the DevOps template for deploying a Function App.

The release runs without any errors and *does* deploy the dropped artifact. However, if I then look at the Function App in the portal I see the message

> Your app is currently in read only mode because you have source control integration enabled.

I wasn't too concerned about this because I don't intend to modify the code in the portal - my assumption is that the read-only state means that I can't modify the function in the portal, right?

And then I also noticed this...

[image]

Why is one of the functions `Disabled`, and how can I deploy so that it is ***en***abled?

Comment: Can you enable your function and deploy again? I deployed app in the same way and I have app enabled.

Comment: I just made an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please enable your function and try again. Deployment should not disable your function, so maybe it was disabled in other way. I tried and it works like this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the warning is not related to the function status. You can use the `Enable` and `Disable` buttons on the function's `Overview` page. These buttons work by changing the value of the `AzureWebJobs.<FUNCTION_NAME>.Disabled` app setting. This function-specific setting is created the first time it's disabled.

[image]

Check documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function#use-the-portal

Regarding the warning, if the function is 'deployed' to Azure, what will be deployed is the compiled file. So this is why it is readonly.

Changes to the code should be done before compiling them into corresponding 'cannot be edited' files, which requires special attention.

But for the modification of the declarative part and the configuration part of the function, this is possible.

Detailed information, you can refer to the following case:

[Azure Functions App is Read Only after publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813405/azure-functions-app-is-read-only-after-publishing)