# How to make function app run as read and write mode

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am new to Azure functions and I am using Azure Function app v3 for my project.
Basically I have to create a empty directory in `bin` but I am getting error as my function app is running in read only more(not sure why)
`Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting`.
[image]

So after I deleted `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE: 1` from `Application configuration but I am not able to see my deployed functions.

when I redeploy it by default `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE: 1` is getting deployed.

Can you please help me how to make function app `read and write` because I want to create folder in kudus where I have to store my file at run time.

Any response is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reason for error could be different. Running app in read only mode does not causes error. Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59816407/1273882

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the deployment mode from 'run from package' to 'web publish' which is an option to enable write access.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies#web-deploy-msdeploy

However 'web publish' is not recommended as run from package adds several benefits.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package

The recommended location for writing data is /home/data

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/42218/python-37-file-system-is-read-only.html